# type mismatch: inferred type is Float but Int was expected (Q2.kts:2:14)

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

```
val x= readLine()!!.toInt()
for (i in 1..x.toFloat()) {
    println(i)

    if (i / 3 == 0)
        print("Triini")

    if (i / 5 == 0)
        print("Pancha")

}
```

I am trying to create a program which inputs a number from the user and prints a list of numbers and if the number is divisible by 3, it reads trinni instead of 3, if 5 then reads pancha. While running this, I found out that if the inputs an integer, kotlin assumes any decimal is a whole number so I tried converting to float but now, it reads this type mismatch: inferred type is Float but Int was expected (Q2.kts:2:14)

Comment: Can you explain more clearly why you added `toFloat()`? I didn't quite understand what "I found out that if the inputs an integer, kotlin assumes any decimal is a whole number" means.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, when a number is an integer, as an example, 2/3 will be 0 but if its a float, 2/3 would be 0.66 if you get what i mean

Comment: I just read your question again - why are you dividing in the first place? Aren't you checking *divisibility*? So it should be `i % 3 == 0`, right?

Comment: Amazing, thank you, only one thing left and if you could help me out, i would seriously appreciate it, I want to delete the number when triini and pancha is printed so like instead of 1 2 3 triini, i want it to be 1 2 triini

Comment: just put the `println(i)` in an else then

Answer (score 1):

Is this maybe what you are going for?

```
fun main() {
val x= readLine()!!.toFloat()
for (i in 1..x.toInt()) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        println("Triini")
    }
    else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        println("Pancha")
    }
    else println(i)

}
```

}